# How do I get Google Colab to automatically recognize which Git Repo a file should be saved to

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, I click `File > Save a Copy In Github`.  It then shows a prompt to `Copy to Github` and there is a dropdown for Repo and a dropdown for branch.

The dropdown for Repo lists all of my Github account's Public repos, which is the right access level.. but why do I have to scroll through all my Repos every time I want to save to Git.  Is there any way for it to remember the Repo, or better yet, recognize that I saved it in the repo already so that must be where it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the issue is that I was not using the url in the format [https://colab.research.google.com/github/[my](https://colab.research.google.com/github/%5Bmy) username]/[my repo] when saving.  When you use that url on colab you're working with something that is understood to be under a specific repo automatically.